# Delete all spaces in part of a string with Perl regex

Tags: regex

I have html code that looks like this:

```
<a href="The Whole World">
```

and a want to make it look like this:

```
<a href="TheWholeWorld">
```

using Perl. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can change it directly in HTML itself right??? I don't understand why to use perl !!!!! are you like to change on run time?

Comment: I repeatedly deal with emails where I need to manually replace them dozens of times, so I'd muuuuuuuuch rather automate it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '<a href="The Whole World">';
$html =~ s/(?<=href=")([^"]+)/ $1 =~ s!\s+!!gr /e;
print $html;
```

This works by changing the text following `href="` up to the following `"`.
The text is modified by a second substitution to delete every space from it.

This uses the `r` modifier of the Perl substitution command which is only available in later versions of Perl.  If you don't a version of Perl that supports it, then use the following:

```
$html =~ s/(?<=href=")([^"]+)/ my $text = $1; $text =~ s!\s+!!g; $text /e;
```

Answer (score 0):

short code fragment

```
$a='<a href="the whole world">';
($c=$a)=~s/("\S+|\S+|")\s*/$1/g;
print $c;
```

how the regexp works:

```
s/("\S+|\S+|")\s*/$1/g;
      ^ ^  ^      ^   ^  ^
      + +  +      +   +  +-- global flag, apply repeatedly
      | |  |      |   +-- substitute in the first capture group
      | |  |      +-- white space, but outside of the capture group
      | |  +-- | alternative operator
      | +-- \S+ match any non zero amount of non white space
      +-- start capturing group
```

So it finds the non white space inside the `"` and puts it in a capture group

The white space between each word does not get in the capture group

This happens repeatedly and the capture groups are copied out to the result but the white space isn't

It is better to use a parser on xml fragments as it is easier to maintain in the long run